# Jasper Reports conditional styles based on export type

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to create a conditional style in jasper template so that its condition will be based on export type? 
For example, i want to have my header set to "HeaderPDF" when export type is pdf and "HeaderCSV" for csv. 
I would like to avoid creating different template files for each extension,but 
I don't know if such thing is even doable, so I will appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own styles and condition them based on some criteria. You can use as criteria a custom parameter that tells the export type (PDF, Excel). You can then decorate the elements with your custom style.

Comment: That makes sense, although i was hoping to do that without additional parameter, but that seems impossible. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: The export type is unknown at Jasper template level. I don't know of a way to figure it out. The server should inform the template report what export type it is so that you can decorate it.

Comment: I guess you are right, it is too early for jasper to know the future export type during compilation time.